# Why does OrderDetails component render first when accessing ConfirmOrder in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

```
<ProtectedRoute exact path="/orders" Component={MyOrders} />
<ProtectedRoute exact path="/order/:id" Component={OrderDetails} />
<ProtectedRoute exact path="/order/confirm" Component={ConfirmOrder} />
```

When I try to access `ConfirmOrder` component the `Orderdetails` component gets rendered first automatically.
When `Orderdetails` component is commented out the rendering is smooth, only `ConfirmOrder` is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to access `ConfirmOrder` component the `OrderDetails`
> component gets rendered first automatically. When `OrderDetails`
> component is commented out the rendering is smooth, only
> `ConfirmOrder` is rendered.

I suspect you are rendering the routes into the [`Switch`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch) component. The `Switch` "Renders the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the location." In other words, it ***exclusively*** matches and renders ***the first*** match it finds in its children. In this case, the route with `path="/order/:id"` matches URL path `"/order/confirm"` ***exactly*** and is the returned route and component, `OrderDetails` is rendered instead of `ConfirmOrder`.

You should keep it in mind that because of the exclusive route matching and rendering and the way the `Switch` checks its children that ***path order and specificity matters***. You should strive to order all the `Route` and `Redirect` components in the ***inverse*** order of path specificity. Render the ***more*** specific paths prior to ***less*** specific paths. For example, `"/order/confirm"` is more specific than `"/order/:id"` is more specific than `"/order"` is more specific than `"/"`. This also eliminates the need to also specify the `exact` prop on all routes.

```
<Switch>
  ...
  <ProtectedRoute path="/orders" component={MyOrders} />

  <ProtectedRoute path="/order/confirm" component={ConfirmOrder} />
  <ProtectedRoute path="/order/:id" component={OrderDetails} />
  ...
  <Route path="/" component={....} />
</Switch>
```